# upload pdf file from storage to firebase in react-native

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, blob

I have been trying to upload PDF file from phone storage to Firebase. Its working fine when I use `react-native-document-picker` to select a pdf file, which returns the path of the file something like **`content://com.android.externalstorage.documents/document/primary%3Adocs%2F' +'<filename>'.pdf'`**
which is then passed to fetch

```
  const response = await fetch(path);
  blob = await response.blob();
```

and then the blob is uploaded to Firebase.

But the problem is that I don't want to pick a document every time. if I don't use `react-native-document-picker` and just curate the exact path return by the module. it gives network error when passed to fetch, so unable to create a blob.
I also tried `react-native-fs` but couldn't figure out how to create a blob of PDF residing in emulated storage.